# How I can serialize an error object with pino?

Tags: node.js, pinojs

I'm just starting out using pino and I am trying to serialize an error object but it doesn't work. This is the code I am using:

```
const log = pino({
    name: "pino",
    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
    level: "trace", 
    serializers: { 
         err: e=> ({ 
             type: e.type, 
             message: e.message,
             stack: e.stack 
         }) 
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late for the answer, but you need to add a "return" to the code:

```
 const log = pino({
    name: "pino",
    timestamp: pino.stdTimeFunctions.isoTime,
    level: "trace", 
    serializers: { 
        err (e){ 
            return:{
                type: e.type, 
                message: e.message,
                stack: e.stack 
            }
        } 
    } 
})
```